# the converse of Schur lemma

Tags: representation-theory

I am interested in the converse of the following form of Schur's lemma:

**Lemma. (Schur)** A group $G$, a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $V$ and a homomorphism $D : G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$ are given. Suppose that $D$ is a irreducible reprsentation. If a linear map $T : V \rightarrow V$ commutes with $D(g)$ for all $g \in G$, then $T$ is some scalar multiple of the identity operator.

Edit) What I want to prove or disprove is the converse of the above:

Suppose that the representation $D : G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$ is reducible. Then there is a linear map $T : V \rightarrow V$ which is not a scalar multiple of the identity such that $T D(g) = D(g) T$, $\forall g\in G$.

When $G$ is a finite group or a compact Lie group, this trivally holds, because every reducible representation of $G$ is decomposable (i.e. fully reducible); if $W \leq V$ is a subspace invariant under $D : G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$, then we can find an invariant subspace $U \leq V$ satisfying $V = W \oplus U$, and $T=\pi_W+2\pi_U$ commutes with every $D(g)$ but is not a scalar multiple of the identity. ($\pi$: projection operators)

**QUESTION.** But what if $G$ is a general group, which admits reducible but indecomposable representations? Does the converse of Schur lemma still hold?

Comment: There is no need to do the $2\pi_U$ trick (unless you want not linear maps but isomorphisms): you can simply take $T=\pi_W$.

Comment: You are completely right.

Comment: (In the algebra case, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2328/when-does-the-converse-to-schurs-lemma-hold)

Comment: In the case of a reductive algebraic group in positive characteristic (which is analogous to the compact Lie group case), this fails for a large class of modules. More precisely, the modules induced from $1$-dimensional representations of the Borel have $1$-dimensional space of endomorphisms (due to Frobenius reciprocity), but they are generally not irreducible.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, let $F$ be the free group on generators $a$ and $b$, and consider the representation of $F$ on $\mathbb C^2$ which maps $a$ and $b$ to $A$ and $B$. This has trivial endomorphism ring, so in particular it is indecomposable, yet it is not simple: the vector $(1,0)$ spans a proper submodule.

Comment: Notice that $BA=A^2B$, so you can factor this representation to get one of the [Baumslag–Solitar group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group) B(1,2) and in fact that is a faithful representation, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119719/when-is-a-baumslag-solitar-group-linear